# Python : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '1s'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print the first letter of the inputted middle name, and print that, instead of the entire middle name

```
first_name = str(input("Please enter your first name: "))
middle_name = str(input("Please enter your middle name: "))
last_name = str(input("Please enter your last name: "))

first_name = first_name.capitalize()
first_name = middle_name.capitalize()
last_name = last_name.capitalize()

name_format = "{first} {middle.1s} {last}"
print(name_format.format(first=first_name, middle=middle_name, last=last_name))
```

Whenever I run the script in Cmd it states

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '1s'.
```

Comment: `{middle.1s}` – What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Print the first letter of the inputted middle name, and print that, instead of the entire middle name, I believe anyway, very new to coding.

Comment: Please link to the documentation where you thought that was the correct syntax to do so. Python indexes elements starting at 0, anyway

Comment: What question are you running into?

Answer (score 1):

You need to slice your string `middle`.  `1s` is not a command Python understands but `[0]` is. See [string slicing](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3).

Your working code:

```
first_name = str(input("Please enter your first name: "))
middle_name = str(input("Please enter your middle name: "))
last_name = str(input("Please enter your last name: "))

first_name = first_name.capitalize()
middle_name = middle_name.upper()
last_name = last_name.capitalize()

name_format = "{first} {middle[0]} {last}"
print(name_format.format(first=first_name, middle=middle_name, last=last_name))
```

Modified:

```
name_format = "{first} {middle[0]} {last}"
```

Slicing strings are versatile.  For example:

```
>>>a='Pythom'
>>>a[0]
P
>>>a[0:]
ythom
>>>a[0:2]
pyt
>>>a[:3]
Pyth
>>>a[-1] 
m
>>>a[-1] = 'n'
>>>a
Python
```

You are doing the same here.  You input your name and slice at a point.  Note that string slicing starts at 0 for the first character and not 1.

Answer (score 1):

`.1s` in a format string is the syntax from the [older `printf`-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting). There, it would have looked liked this:

```
>>> '%s %.1s %s' % ('Guido', 'van', 'Rossum')
'Guido v Rossum'
```

With the [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings), which you are using, this looks a bit different. Format specifiers are to be specified after a colon, like this:

```
>>> '{} {:.1s} {}'.format('Guido', 'van', 'Rossum')
'Guido v Rossum'
```

Or using named groups:

```
>>> '{first} {middle:.1s} {last}'.format(first='Guido', middle='van', last='Rossum')
'Guido v Rossum'
```

This is using the *precision* to limit the string length, as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) (emphasis mine):

> The *precision* is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with `'f'` and `'F'`, or before and after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with `'g'` or `'G'`. **For non-number types the field indicates the maximum field size - in other words, how many characters will be used from the field content.** The *precision* is not allowed for integer values.

(Yes, I am aware that “van” is not a middle name…)

Comment: Got it. Well, I found the duplicate,  anyway